# Best practice of keeping application configuration in plist file

Tags: objective-c, ios, plist, info.plist

This may sound a newbie question, anyway I'm new to iOS dev,

I would like to know what is the best practice of keeping application configuration specific data in plist file. Do you keep it in Info.plist file of the project or in separate plist file ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest (and most user friendly) implementation is trough a Settings.bundle that shows in the Settings application, see [Implementing an iOS Settings Bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH6-SW5) this implies no code just a Root.plist see, the [Settings Application Schema Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PreferenceSettings/Conceptual/SettingsApplicationSchemaReference/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Info.plist is the file with the metadata of the application, you can not write to it from the application, configuration specific data should be is stored in the user defaults plist trough the [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) api.

Additionally you can use the [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore_class/Reference/Reference.html) api for iOS 5+ to store the preferences in the cloud so they are the same for all user devices.

Of course you can do all this manually if you want to write directly to a plist in the documents folder for example and even make that file ubiquitous and store in the cloud also but this is not generally what you want to do.